# Simplify $\binom{m+n}{2} - \binom{m}{2} - \binom{n}{2}$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Simplify $\binom{m+n}{2} - \binom{m}{2} - \binom{n}{2}$.

---

I'm confused on how to approach this problem.  I can't think of any counting argument that will help me, and any 1-1 correspondence.  All solutions are appreciated.

Comment: A few older posts about this (found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbinom%7Ba%7D%7B2%20%7D%2B%5Cbinom%20b2%3D%5Cbinom%7Ba%2Bb%7D2%24&p=1)): [How to algebraically prove $\binom{n+m}{2} = nm + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{m}{2}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/711311),
[Algebraic Proofs in Combinatorics $\binom{n + m}{2} = nm + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{m}{2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/984632), 
[Prove using a combinatorial argument the following statement: $\binom{n+m}{2} = \binom{m}{2} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1488825)

Answer (score 5):

HINT: You have $m$ men and $n$ women in a room. $\binom{m+n}2$ is the number of ways to pick two people in the room. $\binom{m}2$ is the number of ways to pick two of the men, and $\binom{n}2$ is the number of ways to pick two of the women. If you remove those possibilities, what’s left?

Answer (score 2):

Algebraic approach:
Use ${k \choose 2} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ and simplify.

Combinatorial approach:
Suppose you have $m$ distinct red balls and $n$ distinct green balls. You want to choose $2$ of the $m+n$ total balls but you don't want them to both be red and you don't want them to both be green.

Comment: Is $mn-m-n$ the correct answer?

Comment: How did you get that? Always show your work.

Comment: I used the algebra way and got $\frac{m^2-m-n+n^2+2mn-m^2-m-n^2-n}{2}.$

Comment: I just realized my error!  I had to change the signs!  So is $mn$ the correct answer?

Comment: If you want two balls and they cannot be the same color, you need $1$ of the $m$ red balls and $1$ of the $n$ green balls. Yes, there are $m \cdot n$ ways to make that selection.